# Problem with my discord bot currency problem

Tags: discord.py

My discord bot currency system is not working.
I have made a file named amounts.json
But the problem is that the word amounts is not working, please help

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def register(ctx):
  id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
  if id not in amounts:
    registered_em = discord.Embed(title = f"Account Successfully Registered", description = f"You are now registered!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = registered_em)
    _save()
  else:
    registered_already_em = discord.Embed(title = f"Account Already Registered", description = f"You already have an account!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = registered_already_em)

@bot.command()
async def bal(ctx):
  id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
  if id in amounts:
    bal_em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.mention}\'s balence", description = "You have {}  ".format(amounts[id]), color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = bal_em)
  else:
    account_not_registered = discord.Embed(title = f"Account Not Registered", description = f"You do not have an account! Use ?register to register!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = account_not_registered)

@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, target: discord.Member, amount: int):
  self_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
  target_id = str(target.id)
  if self_id not in amounts:
    account_not_registered = discord.Embed(title = f"Account Not Registered", description = f"You do not have an account! use ?register to register!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = account_not_registered)
  elif target_id not in amounts:
    target_no_account = discord.Embed(title = f"Target\'s Account Not Registered", description = f"You can\'t send money to someone that does not have an account! Tell the person to use ?register first in order to send the money!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = target_no_account)
  elif amounts[self_id] < amount:
    no_money = discord.Embed(title = f"Not Enough Money", description = f"You don\'t have enough money!", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = no_money)
  else:
    amounts[self_id] -= amount
    amounts[target_id] += amount
    sent_em = discord.Embed(title = f"Send Successful", description = f"Successfully sent {amount} money to {target.mention}", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = sent_em)
    _save()

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def grab(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    amount = random.randrange(50, 500)
    amounts[id] += amount
    earnt_em = discord.Embed(title = f"Money Earned", description = f"You got {amount} money! Please wait 5 minutes to get more money", color= ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = earnt_em)
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()

bot.run(token)
```

As you see, here is my discord bot currency code.

The error:

```
Ignoring exception in command bal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/PokeShadow-botpy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 212, in bal
    if id in amounts:
NameError: name 'amounts' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/PokeShadow-botpy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/PokeShadow-botpy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/PokeShadow-botpy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'amounts' is not defined
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I have already read the error, it says that the name 'amounts' is not defined.
Should I change the 'amounts' to 'amounts.json'? Or should I do somethings else?

Comment: Consider using an _actual_ database instead of a JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly as described; you haven't actually defined `amounts` anywhere. It is not enough to define a file called `amounts.json` and expect Python to just guess that you want a variable named that.

To start with; you probably want to add:

```py
amounts = {}
```

at the top of your file (assuming it's all one file). This at the very *least* defines a variable called amounts as an empty dictionary. Though; you might want to load the data from the file when it first runs. So we can replace the above with this:

```py
try:
    with open("amounts.json") as f:
        amounts = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    amounts = {}
```

That loads from the file if it exists or sets `amounts` to empty if it doesn't. This should at least get your code working.

Might be a good idea to go over some beginner Python courses to give you some more understanding on how the language works.